How to get the last modify entries in a big querytable
I have a bigquery table with the following record
_id | hours | dateUpdated
id1 | 1 |2024-05-14 16:00:57 UTC
id1 | 2 |2024-05-15 16:00:57 UTC
id2 | 5 |2024-05-15 16:00:57 UTC

I would like to return the last updated record .The record from 2024-05-14 should be excluded because we have newer update
id1 | 2 |2024-05-15 16:00:57 UTC
id2 | 5 |2024-05-15 16:00:57 UTC

How can do this in BigQuery SQL.
Thanks for your help

Do you want to get records from last day only ?

I just wanted get the last row that was update for each _id

Use ROW_NUMBER() if you need to retrieve the most recently updated single row, but if you need to retrieve multiple rows for each ID, then use RANK().
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY _id ORDER BY dateUpdated DESC) rn
    FROM mytable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1

Explanations :
ROW_NUMBER() : assigns a distinct number for each row within the partition.
RANK() assigns same rank for rows with identical values (dateUpdated in this case).
